# Asus Taichi won't detect second display

Tags: laptop, display, display-settings, laptop-display

It worked great for about a week.  Now when you hit the magic button and the software pops up the displays aren't available.

[image]

When I try to launch Asus Screen Share, I get the following error:

[image]

Only one monitor shows up in the device manager.  I've scanned for hardware changes and it doesn't find anything.  I've rebooted multiple times, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a hardware switch on the left side to disable the external display; confirm that it is not disabled.

Comment: Not sure why you think the image was "rude"... And technically it wasn't pointless... the point it made was that I feel stupid for missing the switch.  But I agree, the pic doesn't need to be here.